# JSF issue with Scopes

Tags: jsf

Following is my managed bean code:

```
public class SelectEntries implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1217595612573680L;

private List<SelectEntry> selectEntries = new ArrayList<SelectEntry>();

private SelectEntry selectEntry;

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    selectEntries.add(new SelectEntry("1001", new CheckEntry("Line 1"),
            new CheckEntry("Line 2"), new CheckEntry("Line 3")));
    selectEntries.add(new SelectEntry("1002", new CheckEntry("Line 4"),
            new CheckEntry("Line 5"), new CheckEntry("Line 6")));
    selectEntries.add(new SelectEntry("1003", new CheckEntry("Line 7"),
            new CheckEntry("Line 8"), new CheckEntry("Line 9")));
}

public List<SelectEntry> getSelectEntries() {
    return selectEntries;
}

public void setSelectEntries(List<SelectEntry> selectEntries) {
    this.selectEntries = selectEntries;
}

public SelectEntry getSelectEntry() {
    return selectEntry;
}

public void setSelectEntry(SelectEntry selectEntry) {
    this.selectEntry = selectEntry;
}

public String getTemplatesString() {

    String templatesString = "";
    for (CheckEntry oneCheckEntry : getSelectEntry().getCheckEntries()) {
        if (oneCheckEntry.getCheck()) {
            templatesString += oneCheckEntry.getName();
        }
    }

    return templatesString;
}
}
```

Here is the SelectEntry class:

```
public class SelectEntry implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7298341984562171094L;

private String name;

private List<CheckEntry> checkEntries = new ArrayList<CheckEntry>();

public SelectEntry(String name, CheckEntry... checkEntries) {
    this.name = name;
    if (checkEntries != null) {
        this.checkEntries.addAll(Arrays.asList(checkEntries));
    }
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<CheckEntry> getCheckEntries() {
    return checkEntries;
}

public void setCheckEntries(List<CheckEntry> checkEntries) {
    this.checkEntries = checkEntries;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    SelectEntry other = (SelectEntry) obj;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    return true;
}

}
```

And the CheckEntry class:

```
public class CheckEntry implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1730874183104100662L;

private String name;

private Boolean check;

public CheckEntry(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Boolean getCheck() {
    return check;
}

public void setCheck(Boolean check) {
    this.check = check;
}

}
```

I have a simple function in the managed bean to get create a String on the bases of which check entries have been selected.This only functions with SessionScope and if I use RequestScope, the boolean values of CheckEntries are null and I get runtime error. Why is it so?

Comment: have you tried with `ViewScope`?

Comment: With ViewScope, the ajax content is not rendered at all

Comment: That should not happend. ViewScope works with ajax. I'd look for reason why it does not work with a ViewScope, because RequestScope is useless in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As per JEE7 tutorial:

> Request (@RequestScoped): Request scope persists during a single HTTP
>   request in  a web application. In an application like hello1, where
>   the application consists of  a single request and response, the bean
>   uses request scope.

So once your page is loaded, the resquest scoped backing bean is gone for subsequent interactions (even ajax).

You should note that it is encouraged to use the scopes from package javax.enterprise.context
For your application, looks like the minimum scope required is ViewScope. Since javax.enterprise.context doesn't implement view scope, you might consider using [Omnifaces](http://omnifaces.org).